# Vertically (only) resizable windows form in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, resize

I have a situation where it would be beneficial to me to allow my windows form to be resized by the user, but only vertically. After some searching, it seems like there isn't much on this particular subject. Is it possible?

Comment: @Will: That depends what the form is displaying.  There are (some) cases where this is a good idea.

Comment: @slaks never seen it.  Seen plenty of apps that think they know how big a form should be.  Visual Studio still has a few of them.  These forms have one thing in common--the people who made them were wrong about the "right" size.  In all cases, let the user decide what the size of the form is, or risk damnation.  (Full disclosure, I risk damnation.  I am ashamed.)

Comment: @Will: How about Virtual PC 2007?

Comment: @dada686 On Vista, Freecell can be resized and scales, which is great. 
I came here because I have a 3-line window: two text fields and a button. So resizing it vertically makes no sense, right...? Well, I'm not so sure any more. For vertical resizing, I could make the text fields taller and the font larger! It's an unusual feature, but it doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You need to set the form's `MinimumSize` and `MaximumSize` properties to two sizes with different heights but equal widths.

If you don't want the horizontal resize cursor to appear at all, you'll need to handle the [`WM_NCHITTEST`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645618%28VS.85%29.aspx) message, like this:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
    base.WndProc(ref m);
    switch (m.Msg) {
        case 0x84: //WM_NCHITTEST
            var result = (HitTest)m.Result.ToInt32();
            if (result == HitTest.Left || result == HitTest.Right)
                m.Result = new IntPtr((int)HitTest.Caption);
            if (result == HitTest.TopLeft || result == HitTest.TopRight)
                m.Result = new IntPtr((int)HitTest.Top);
            if (result == HitTest.BottomLeft || result == HitTest.BottomRight)
                m.Result = new IntPtr((int)HitTest.Bottom);

            break;
    }
}
enum HitTest {
    Caption = 2,
    Transparent = -1,
    Nowhere = 0,
    Client = 1,
    Left = 10,
    Right = 11,
    Top = 12,
    TopLeft = 13,
    TopRight = 14,
    Bottom = 15,
    BottomLeft = 16,
    BottomRight = 17,
    Border = 18
}
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of this... Very nice! And thanks for the WndProc particulars of hiding that resize cursor!

Comment: Just a comment... shouldn't you make the HitTest.Left and .Right return None and not Caption?  Using Caption makes the window draggable at those locations, no?

Comment: @MarqueIV: Yes; I consider that a feature.

Comment: I agree it's a nice feature to have--to be able to drag the window around from someplace other than the caption, but if you're going that route, I'd do it for anywhere where NCHitTest would normally return None so you can drag it from other parts of the client area too.  Without allowing that, there isn't any distinction or feedback to the user that the edges have a different behavior whereas if it always moved regardless, it would.  Of course playing my own adversary, I could also say allowing moving from anywhere other than the caption is also a non-consistent interface so there's that too.

Answer (score 13):

Just an idea...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    int _width;

    public Form1() {
        _width = this.Width;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e) {
        this.Width = _width;
        base.OnResize(e);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: please note that the min/max size solutions work much better than this hack :)

Comment: Beat me to it. +1 For other solutions, I'm not sure that it's possible to actually have a max/min width without also setting a max/min height. This solution will allow you to resize the form, but it will rubber-band back to it's original width.

Comment: @George: You can just set a small minimum and a very large maximum.

Answer (score 7):

Set the max & min size for the width of the form only.

Comment: Be sure to do so in the Load event, not the constructor.  Or automatic scaling will clip the form content.

Comment: If you leave the height component of the MinimumSize and MaximumSize properties at 0 but set a width, it will constrain the window to its minimum height.  MinimumSize and MaximumSize constraints are only ignored when both components are zero - if one's set and the other is left at zero, it will enforce both components literally.

Comment: Do it in the properties pane at Design Time. There's no need to use any code to make the form only scroll vertically.

Answer (score 3):

Let the FormBorderStyle to Resizable and set MaximumSize and MinimumSize = new Size(this.Width, 0)

**Correction**:

```
this.MinimumSize = new Size(this.Width, 0);
this.MaximumSize = new Size(this.Width, Int32.MaxValue);
```

Comment: MinimumSize and MaximumSize components are only interpreted as "no limit" when BOTH components are zero.

Comment: @SLaks, You're right! the height need to be set to different value in min and max sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Just set your form.MinimumSize.Width = form.MaximumSize.Width = 100 (or whatever width you want).

Comment: You cannot assign the Width directly as form.MinimunSize or form.MaximumSize returns a value type, not a reference.

Comment: It was not a working code sample, just an idea of what should be set up.

Comment: I fail to understand how people forget to use logic when trying to understand a simple statement. +1

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the "rubber-banding" effect of @orsogufo's solution:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.MinimumSize = new Size(500, 0);
    this.MaximumSize = new Size(500, Screen.AllScreens.Max(s => s.Bounds.Height));
}
```

It won't correctly adjust its maximum height to accommodate a larger screen if you resize the screen bounds, but for static screen sizes it works great.