# How to stop looping in Resizing event of Winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress-windows-ui

I am using Winform. I have Resize event. When I call the event, it call itself again and again. Following is my code.

```
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int tabHeight = 100;
     this.Height = tabHeight + 20;
     this.Top = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height / 2) - (this.Height / 2);
}
```

Event call itself again and again from `this.Height = tabHeight + 20;` 
How can I stop looping of call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a possible solution:

```
bool _resizing;

private void Form_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_resizing) return;
    _resizing = true;

    int tabHeight = 100;
    Height = tabHeight + 20;
    Top = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height / 2) - (Height / 2);

    _resizing = false;
}
```

But there are some better ways to resize the window in only one direction:
[Vertically (only) resizable windows form in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140882/vertically-only-resizable-windows-form-in-c-sharp)