# Set UserControl's max height without setting max width

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, windows-forms-designer

I have a UserControl for a ComboBox with predefined values. I that the programmer who uses this control will be able to stretch the control horizontally, but not vertically.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2140908/1925272), [@SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks) suggests to set the `MaximumSize` property, but than, I would have to limit the width, which I don't want to.

So how to accomplish that?

Comment: Why not set the `MaximumSize` to `(int.MaxValue, Height)`?

Comment: It is almost always a better idea to derive your own class from ComboBox.  You'll inherit all of its default behavior, including the way it resizes.  Only use UserControl when you need to combine multiple controls.

Answer (score 1):

You can override `SetBoundsCore` and make it to use height of `ComboBox` as height of your control:

```
protected override void SetBoundsCore(int x, int y, int width, int height,
    BoundsSpecified specified)
{
    base.SetBoundsCore(x, y, width, comboBox1.Height, specified);
}
```

**Note 1:** If your `UserControl` contains just a `ComboBox`, it's better to derive from `ComboBox` rather than creating a user control containing a `ComboBox`

**Note 2:** You can make it obvious in the designer that control can just resized from left or right by creating a new `ControlDesigner` and overriding `SelectionRules` property. To do so, add a reference to `System.Design` assembly and then create a custom designer:

```
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;
public class MyControlDesigner : ControlDesigner
{
    public override SelectionRules SelectionRules
    {
        get
        {
            return SelectionRules.LeftSizeable |
                   SelectionRules.RightSizeable |
                   SelectionRules.Moveable;
        }
    }
}
```

Then it's enough to decorate your custom control with designer attribute this way:

```
[Designer(typeof(MyControlDesigner))]
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any question about this post. It's the best solution that you can use for creating a fixed-height control.